# Error consuming api with laravel on windows 10?

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest, curl

[image]

cURL error 35: error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados

I'm trying to consume this api using laravel and php 8 on windows, but it's returning this error cUrl 35, I don't know what it could be when I run the project in php7.4 here locally it works, what could it be?

I already checked some php settings

Comment: This feels like laravel needs to be configured to use TLS1.2. This might be a place to start https://support.stripe.com/questions/upgrade-your-php-integration-from-tls-1-0-to-tls-1-2?locale=en-GB

Comment: You're trying to connect to a bad server. Running it through http://ssllabs.com/ssltest/ will probably tell you what's wrong. But if it's not your server, nothing much you can do other than run your code on an old system that accepts legacy encryption.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue consuming the same site, of IBGE the only thing that solve my problem was send the request without the HTTPS. Isn't the best to do but was the way to solve my problem
[image]